# How can I combine pagination and filtering in php?

Tags: php, database, checkbox, pagination, filtering

I would like to display some products from database and use pagination as well as checkboxes for filtering. My pagination is working fine. And when I click checkboxes and press "submit," I do get filtered results on the first page. However, when I move to the second or any other page, the checkboxes automatically become unchecked and the filtering gets lost.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="iPhone">iPhone<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="iPad">iPad<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="Samsung">Samsung<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="Huawei">Huawei<br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php include 'display_products.php';?>
```

My pagination is made this way:

```
for ($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++) {
  if ($page == $page_active) {
    echo '<a class="page-number this-active" href="index.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
  } else {
    echo '<a class="page-number" href="index.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
  }
}
```

In order to apply filtering I use an IF statement:

```
if (isset($_GET['brand'])) {
  $filter = implode('","',$_GET['brand']);
  $sql='SELECT * FROM products WHERE brand IN ("' . $filter . '") LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<div><h3>' . $row['title'] . '</h3><img src="' . $row['image'] . '"<h4>' . $row['price']. '</h4></div>';
  }
} //else display all products from the table of the database
```

I assume that when I go to the next page, my checkboxes get unchecked, this $_GET['brand'] becomes empty and the "else" statement is activated. I tried to find solutions for this problem, but some of them were not effective and some were too hard for me to understand (I am a beginner). Could you please explain in simple terms how to keep the checkboxes checked and how to keep the filtering throughout all the pages?  I saw such ideas as "use session" or "keep the data in url," but I can't figure out how to implement it. So if you are more specific, I would be super grateful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please share more code including your pagination..

Comment: you should store user filtering options in $_SESSION and update them in every post

Comment: Your SQL query is open for SQL injection, better fix that. And where's the code for pagination? Why not add the IDs of all checked boxes to the paginated URL?

Comment: I have added the code of my pagination, thanks

Comment: Right now I am learning how to make filtering and pagination. After I reach my goal I will definitely proceed to SQL injection. Concerning IDs added to the URL, I am afraid I don’t know how it works. If you could tell a bit more about it, that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use PHP to generate the `brands` checkboxes ( something that has merit if there are many brands which can be altered any time by an administrator for example ) then perhaps the following might give an idea how to maintain the `checked` status of each checkbox.

The following is a rough idea how you might accomplish the stated goal - I hope you might find it of help.

```
<form method='get'>
    <fieldset>
        <?php
        # an array of brands.. this could likely be from the database
        $brands=['iPhone','iPad','Samsung','Huawei','Nokia','Sony','LG','Motorola','Blackberry','Vodafone','Alcatel','Razer','Google'];
            
        # get either the current GET array or an empty array
        $params=$_GET;
        
        # add the brands checkboxes
        foreach( $brands as $brand ){
            # maintain the checked status by checking if the current brand is in the `brand[]` querystring value
            $checked=isset( $_GET['brand'] ) && in_array( $brand, $_GET['brand'] ) ? ' checked' : '';
            
            # print the checkbox
            printf('<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="%1$s"%2$s>%1$s<br />', $brand, $checked );
        }
        ?>
        <!-- a hidden field will ensure the page variable is set each time the form is submitted -->
        <input type='hidden' name='page' value='<?=isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;?>' />
        <input type='submit' />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='paging'>
    <?php
    
    # some pseudo paging links... should be derived dynamically ~ this is just for demo
    for( $i=1; $i <= 10; $i++ ){
            
        $params['page']=$i;
        $active=isset( $_GET['page'] ) && intval( $_GET['page'] )==$i ? ' class="active"' : '';
            
        printf('<a href="?%2$s" %3$s>[ %1$d ]</a>', $i, http_build_query( $params ), $active );
    }           
    ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This sounds very good, I appreciate your quick and detailed response. I will try to implement it and will see how it works. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you again. I have been able to understand the logic of your code and adjust it according to my needs. I am happy with the result

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to offer some measure of assistance to you. Good luck with the rest of your project

Comment: Just in case someone else uses this code, I'd suggest to change the value of the hidden input to simply 1 (<input type='hidden' name='page' value='1'>). Then every time the user hits the button 'submit,' he will go to the first page. Otherwise, if he is on, let's say, page 15 and then changes filtering options so that there are 14 pages or fewer, he will still be on page 15 and it will be blank.